# How can I let my React app treat each component instance separately?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, tinymce, react-router-dom, tinymce-5

I am trying to test how TinyMCE handles multiple editors inside React.

In this small example, I just have 3, but there could be up to 100 of them.

My problem is, that I don't think each are being treated as separate instances, but rather one instance.

I don't get any errors, but when I edit one, the edits appears in all 3.

Is there a way to let TinyMCE know which editor is which?

```
import React from 'react';
import TinyMCEComponent from './TinyMCEComponent';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_1">Editor One</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_2">Editor Two</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_3">Editor Three</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/editor_1">
            <TinyMCEComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/editor_2">
            <TinyMCEComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/editor_3">
            <TinyMCEComponent />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

And this is where TinyMCE is:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Editor } from '@tinymce/tinymce-react';

const TinyMCEComponent = () => {

const handleEditorChange = (content, editor) => {
    console.log('Content was updated:', content);
}

return (
    <Editor
        apiKey="abc123"
        initialValue="<p>This is the initial content of the editor</p>"
        init={{
            height: 500,
            menubar: false,
            plugins: [
                'advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor'
            ],
            toolbar:
                'undo redo | formatselect | bold italic backcolor | help'
        }}
        onEditorChange={handleEditorChange}
    />
);
}

export default TinyMCEComponent;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to give each a `key`.

```
import React from 'react';
import TinyMCEComponent from './TinyMCEComponent';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function BasicExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_1">Editor One</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_2">Editor Two</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/editor_3">Editor Three</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <hr />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/editor_1">
            <TinyMCEComponent key="ed1" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/editor_2">
            <TinyMCEComponent key="ed2" />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/editor_3">
            <TinyMCEComponent key="ed3" />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what does the TinyMCEComponent do with the key?  I mean, how can I use that key in TinyMCE?  thanks!

Comment: The `key` prop just tells react that the two are different. See the react [docs on the subject](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). In the `TinyMCEComponent` you'll need to pass another prop like an `id` to load different data.